# linear algebra problem combined with calculus concept ...

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P_3 = \left\{at^3 + bt^2 + ct + d \mid a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$.  The linear transformation $T \colon P_3 \to P_3$ is defined as $T(p) = p'' + p' + p$, where $p'$ and $p''$ are the first and second derivatives, respectively, of $p \in P_3$. Prove that for every $q \in P_3$, there exists exactly one $p\in P_3$ such that $T(p) = q.$

I have no idea to solve it. Would anyone mind if helping me?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: thanks for your formatting of my text, this is my first time to ask here xd
and before, I really have no idea, dont know what to try :(((

Answer (score 1):

Two points have to be proven : the existence of such a polynomial $p$ as well as its uniqueness.

**Existence.**
We would like to show that $\forall q = \alpha t^3 + \beta t^2 + \gamma t + \delta \in P_3$ $\exists p = at^3 + bt^2 + ct + d \in P_3$ such that $T(p) = q$. Note that $T(p) = p'' + p' + p = at^3 + (3a+b)t^2 + (6a+2b+c)t + d$. In consequence, the relation $T(p) = q$ translates as the following system of linear equations :
$$
\begin{cases}
   \alpha = a \\
   \beta = 3a + b \\
   \gamma = 6a + 2b + c \\
   \delta = d
\end{cases}
\quad \Longrightarrow \quad
\begin{cases}
   a = \alpha \\
   b = \beta - 3\alpha \\
   c = \gamma - 2\beta \\
   d = \delta
\end{cases}
$$

**Uniqueness.**
Assume that there exists two polynomials $p_1,p_2 \in P_3$ such that $T(p_1) = T(p_2) = q$. Then, one has by linearity $T(p_1-p_2) = T(p_1) - T(p_2) = q - q = 0$, so that $(a_1-a_2)t^3 + (b_1-b_2)t^2 + (c_1-c_2)t + (d_1-d_2) = 0$, hence $a_1 = a_2$, etc., and $p_1 = p_2$ in the end.

Comment: You can save half of the work by using the Linear Algebra fact, that a linear map between two vector spaces of equal finite dimension is injective if and only if it is surjective if and only if the kernel of $T$ is $\{0\}$.

Comment: thank you! this solution is quite friendly to comprehend~

Comment: @姚权维  You're welcome ! You might consider upvoting my answer in that case ;)

Comment: @Abezhiko I am new to here, I appreciate your help so much, but it needs at least 15 reputation from my account to upvote :(((

Answer (score 0):

If you know rank-nullity theorem and if you are comfortable working directly with linear transformation then denote by $R$ the range space and note that

$T(1) = 1 \implies 1\in R$

$T(x) = 1 + x = T(1) + x \implies T(x - 1) = x \implies x\in R$

$T(x^2) = 1 + 2x + x^2  = T(1) + 2T(x - 1) + x^2 \implies T(x^2-2x+1) = x^2  \implies x^2\in R$

Similarly you can show that $x^3\in R$. Also you don't really need all the above calculations if you understand that Range is vector space. Using that you know $1\in R$ immediately. Then $T(x) = 1 + x$ combined with $1\in R$ gives you $x\in R$. Proceeding like this you get $x^2, x^3\in R$ hence $R = V$ and by rank-nullity null space is $0$. And if you are not familiar with rank-nullity theorem you can obtain a more direct proof of the result that $T : V \to V$ is injective if and only if it is subjective. This is obviously for finite dimensional vector spaces only.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that:

$(at^3+bt^2+ct+d)''+(at^3+bt^2+ct+d)'+(at^3+bt^2+ct+d)=0$
$\implies at^3+(b+3a)t^2+(c+2b+6a)t+(d+c+2b)=0$
$\implies a=b=c=d=0$
so, $Ker T$ consists of zero polynomial only which suggests $T$ is *one-one*. Now $T$ is from $P_3$ to itself so $T$ must be *onto* as well.